# Handling trailing slash in Cloud Function with Express

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to handle an HTTP request to a cloud function ***without*** a trailing slash `***.cloudfunctions.net/app` and redirect to the one ***with*** a trailing slash `***.cloudfunctions.net/app/`.

I can't figure out inside a Cloud Function how to properly detect this case.

Here's an example

```
const app = require('express')();
module.exports.app = app;

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
      url: req.url,
      path: req.path
    });
})
```

If I navigate to both `***.cloudfunctions.net/app` and to `***.cloudfunctions.net/app/` (with the slash), I get the same result

```
{"url":"/", "path":"/"}
```

Any idea how to detect a lack of a trailing space in the request in Node/Express middleware?

**EDIT**: clarified my question

Comment: Why do you need to redirect, if they already end up in the same place?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I want to output an HTML file that contains relative urls to its css/js, for example `<script src="assets/client.js">` These relative URLs would resolve differently depending on the trailing slash: `/assets/client.js` (without slash) vs `/app/assets/client.js` (with slash)